# CTCI Making Anagrams - Getting incorrect output

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stringbuilder, anagram

I'm writing a function that takes two strings and is supposed to remove characters from one or both until both strings have the exact same characters. Then, I am supposed to return the number of characters that needed to be removed to achieve anagram status for both. I'm getting strange output (and passing one test case). Can anyone tell me where my function goes wrong?

```
public class Solution {
static int makeAnagram(String a, String b, int aLeng, int bLeng) {
    StringBuilder stringA = new StringBuilder(a);
    StringBuilder stringB = new StringBuilder(b);    

    int result=0;
    for (int i=0; i<stringB.length();i++)
    {
        if (a.contains(b.substring(i)))
            continue;
        else
            stringB.deleteCharAt(i);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<stringA.length();i++)
    {  
        //if(stringB.toString().contains(stringA.toString().substring(i)))
        if (b.contains(a.substring(i)))
             continue;
        else
            stringA.deleteCharAt(i);
    }
    if (stringA.length()==stringB.length())
         result = (aLeng-stringA.length()) + (bLeng-stringB.length());
    else
         result = -1;
    return result;
}

private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new                                             FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

    String a = scanner.nextLine();

    String b = scanner.nextLine();

    int aLeng = a.length();
    int bLeng = b.length();

    int res = makeAnagram(a, b, aLeng, bLeng);

    bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(res));
    bufferedWriter.newLine();

    bufferedWriter.close();

    scanner.close();
}
}
```

**Test Case 1**

```
Input (stdin)
cde
abc
Your Output (stdout)
4
Expected Output
4
```

**Test Case 2**

```
Input (stdin)
fcrxzwscanmligyxyvym
jxwtrhvujlmrpdoqbisbwhmgpmeoke
Your Output (stdout)
-1
Expected Output
30
Compiler Message
Wrong Answer
```

**Test Case 3**

```
Input (stdin)
showman
woman
Your Output (stdout)
6
Expected Output
2
Compiler Message
Wrong Answer
```

Comment: In the last example, if you remove the `s` and the `h`, you're left with "owman" and "woman". Those are anagrams of each other. That's why the answer is 2.

Comment: yep, i know that. more confused why my method isn't returning 2.

Comment: You need to count each character in each string, and then compare the counts. For example, if the first string is "aabbaa" and the second string is "bbbaaa", then the counts are `{a=4, b=2}` for the first string and `{a=3, b=3}` for the second string. So the answer is 2 because the difference in counts for `a` is 1 and the difference in counts for `b` is 1.

Comment: In your code, it seems like a single character in the first string could match multiple characters in the other string. You're also deleting characters from the string that you're iterating over, which causes characters to be skipped.

Comment: @user3386109 1) I am counting the characters in each string that are being removed as well as the original character count. 2) this i am aware of 3)how does it cause characters to be skipped and what could be done to fix it?

Comment: Well let's say that string `b` is "abcde", and the loop has reached `i=2`. In other words, the loop is examining character 'c'. If you delete the 'c', the string is now "abde" and the letter at index 2 is now the 'd'. But 'd' is never checked because the  `i++` in the `for` statement advances the index to 3.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use substring which is costlier in case of the bigger string. You can use below algorithm. I recommend giving a name as checkAnagram instead makeAnagram

```
string_counter_map = {}
for char in string1:
    if char in string_counter_map:
        string_counter_map[char] += 1
 for char in string2:
    if char in string_counter_map:
        string_counter_map[char] -= 1
    else:
        string_counter_map[char] = 1
```

Assuming if all characters string_counter_map contains zero it is anagram else it won't be.